# Dynamically access object function within module exports

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function module.exports as shown below

```
const eventHandler = {
  login: () => {
    console.log(`login main -> event handler called....!`);
  },
  execute: (prop) => {
    console.log(`event name ${prop}....!`);
    eventHandler.login();
  },
};

module.exports = eventHandler;
```

here i don't want to use switch case in order to call different functions based on prop.

So, I'm looking for something like below to dynamically call a function

```
eventHandler[`${prop}`];
```

The above one is not working. It's just an idea of what I needed.

How to avoid switch case and achieve above thing ?

Comment: The above does work provided of course that `prop` is `'login' ` or `'execute'`

Comment: This will work, you just need to invoke it with brackets (and pass any props through there)

`eventHandler['${prop}']();`

Comment: And by the way, your instinct is good. It would be quite silly to use a switch

Comment: @Gandzal Hey that's the answer thank you

Comment: For sure, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so silly. But for beginners like me it was confusing a lot.

as @Gandzal said in comment one must add '()'

```
eventHandler[`${prop}`]();
```

Comment: I can always add it as an answer, so you can accept it.